Kendo-pdf-export doesn't rendering the charactors in correct order?
I used unicode non-english font in .ttf format to export to the .scss file of angular. in the web page getting the font-family but when I export using kendo-pdf-export it doesn't come in correct word.
In the web it shows
In exported pdf shows like this
how can I fix.
I tried with 2,3 fonts and both supports unicode
I used angular and kendo ui. pdf export not getting correctly. How can I fix?

Your problem is the kendo-pdf-export, not the font. The text uses a complex script that requires additional text shaping operations when it is included in PDF.
Contact Kendo support to see if they support your script for proper PDF export.
